# Filter IP and MAC address from stream of data packets with regular expression in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I need to use **TCL**'s regular expression to check my src ip (11.1.1.1) and src mac addr (00:40:43:b9:32:94) from the stream of data as below:

```
Frame 5603: 90 bytes on wire (720 bits), 90 bytes captured (720 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: NokiaSie_b9:32:94 (00:40:43:b9:32:94), Dst: OmronTat_53:6a:5b (00:00:0a:53:6a:5b)
802.1Q Virtual LAN, PRI: 0, CFI: 0, ID: 1
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 11.1.1.1 (11.1.1.1), Dst: 13.1.1.1 (13.1.1.1)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 49184 (49184), Dst Port: 49152 (49152)
Data (44 bytes)
```

Comment: so you want to do this with tcl?

Comment: yes ,i need to filter it out using tcl script

Comment: only (00:40:43:b9:32:94) and (11.1.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
set data "
    Frame 5603: 90 bytes on wire (720 bits), 90 bytes captured (720 bits)
    Ethernet II, Src: NokiaSie_b9:32:94 (00:40:43:b9:32:94), Dst: OmronTat_53:6a:5b (00:00:0a:53:6a:5b)
    802.1Q Virtual LAN, PRI: 0, CFI: 0, ID: 1
    Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 11.1.1.1 (11.1.1.1), Dst: 13.1.1.1 (13.1.1.1)
    User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 49184 (49184), Dst Port: 49152 (49152)
    Data (44 bytes)
"
regexp {Src:.*?(\([^)]+\)).*?Src:.*?(\([^)]+\))} $data match mac ip
puts "mac = $mac"
puts "ip = $ip"
```

Output:

```
mac = (00:40:43:b9:32:94)
ip = (11.1.1.1)
```

Comment: Hi Alec , one problem i am facing is that the stream of data packets includes all the packets including those which have Src ip other than (11.1.1.1) and Src Mac other than (00:40:43:b9:32:94). I that case the regexp given by you doesnt grep exact info . Can you plz help ?

Comment: I would like to help but I don't have your **that case**.